# Another example of a connected but non path connected set

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I'm looking at the polar graph of the function $f:[\frac\pi2,\infty)\to \Bbb{R}^2$ defined by $\ r=f(\theta)=e^{\frac 1 \theta}$, the graph of this is the set of points of the form $(e^{\frac 1 \theta}\cos(\theta),e^{\frac 1 \theta}\sin(\theta))$.

That set(which happens to be the polar graph) is path-connected since it's the image of a path-connected set by a  continuous function.

The closure of this set is thus connected, but by graphing the curve the closure looks like the graph and the unit circle. Is the closure not path-connected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the closure isn't path connected. To connect a point with $r > 1$ in the set to a point with $r = 1$ in the closure, you'd need a path winding around the unit disk infinitely many times, but that isn't possible since a path is uniformly continuous, and hence a path in the closure can only wind finitely often around the unit disk.

Let us denote $\Gamma = f([\pi/2,+\infty))$. Then $\overline{\Gamma} = \Gamma \cup S^1$ where the union is disjoint. Let $\alpha \colon [0,1] \to \overline{\Gamma}$ be a path with $r_0 := \lVert \alpha(0) \rVert > 1$. Since $\Gamma$ intersects each circle $\{(x,y) : x^2+y^2 = r^2\}$ with $r > 1$ in exactly one point, we can write the polar angle as a function of the radius while $\alpha(t)\in\Gamma$,

$$\varphi(t) = \frac{1}{\log \lVert\alpha(t)\rVert}.$$

Thus to reach the radius $0 < r < r_0$, the polar angle must traverse the entire interval $\left[ \frac{1}{\log r_0}, \frac{1}{\log r}\right]$ and hence $\alpha$ must wind at least

$$n(r) = \left\lfloor \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\frac{1}{\log r} - \frac{1}{\log r_0}\right)\right\rfloor$$

times around the unit disk. But each full winding around the unit disk contains points where the polar angle differs by $\pi$, and therefore points whose distance is $> 2$.

But, since $[0,1]$ is compact, $\alpha$ is uniformly continuous, so there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for $\lvert t -s\rvert \leqslant \delta$ we have $\lVert \alpha(t) - \alpha(s)\rVert \leqslant 2$. Thus $\alpha$ can wind at most

$$k(\alpha) = \left\lceil \frac{1}{2\delta}\right\rceil$$

times around the unit disk, and therefore

$$n(\lVert\alpha(t)\rVert) < k(\alpha)+1,$$

which implies

$$\lVert \alpha(t)\rVert > \exp \left(\frac{1}{(\log r_0)^{-1} + 2\pi(k(\alpha)+2)}\right) > 1,$$

and hence a path starting in $\Gamma$ never can reach the unit circle.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why the path would need to wind around the unit disk infinitely many times and why the path can only do so finitely many time?

Comment: I've elaborated, hope that clarifies it. Otherwise ask.