# Connected sets. Connected by paths. Locally constant functions. Incomplete solution.

Tags: real-analysis, path-connected

> Prove that
>
> (a) Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$. A aplication $f: X \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is said locally constant when for each $x \in X$, there is a $B(x,\delta)$ such that $f|(B(x,\delta)\cap X)$ is constant. $X$ is connected if only if all aplication locally constant $f: X \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is constant.
>
> (b) The closure of a set connected by paths may not be connected by paths.

**For (a).** $(\Longrightarrow)$ Suppose that $X$ is connected. Let $x_{0} \in X$ and $Y = \lbrace y \in X\,|\,f(y) = f(x_{0})\rbrace$. Given any $x \in X$, the neighborhood when $f$ is locally constant is contained in $Y$, so $Y$ is open. Since $f$ is locally constant, by definition of locally constant, $f$ must be continuous. Thus, $Y$ is closed because if $y_{n} \in Y$ and $y_{n} \to y$, then $\lim f(y_{n}) = f(y) = f(x_{0}) \Longrightarrow y \in Y$. But $Y^{c}$ is open and $Y \cup Y^{c} = X$, then $Y$ or $Y^{c}$ are empty sets (by hypothesis, $X$ is connected). Since $x_{0} \in Y$, so $Y = X$.

That is right?

$(\Longleftarrow)$ I have no idea.

---

**For (b).** I know the a set connected by paths is connected and the closure of a connected set is connected. A set $X$ is connected by paths if given $a,b \in X$ there is a path subset in $X$ that connects $a$ and $b$. I couldn't expand anything.

---

Any hint? Thanks for the advance!

*PS:* I don't know much about metric spaces, so I would like hints that only involve properties of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: For part (b), consider the graph of $x \mapsto \sin(x^{-1})$ on $x \in (0,1]$.  It's path connected since it's the graph of a continuous function, but it's well-known that its closure is not path connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a)$: suppose that $X$ has some separation by open sets $(U,V)$. Define $f:X \to \mathbb R$ by $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, \text{ if $x \in U$} \\ 0, \text{ if $x \in V$} \end{cases}$$

This $f$ is locally constant but not constant.

For $b)$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005925/another-example-of-a-connected-but-non-path-connected-set?rq=1).

Comment: I apologize, I stated item b) in the wrong way.

Comment: @LucasCorrêa added a link!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that in b) what you really want to know is wheher the closure of a path-connected set must be path-connectd. It doesn't have to be. Take$$Y=\left\{\left(x,\sin\left(\frac1x\right)\right)\,\middle|\,x>0\right\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2.$$It is path-connected, but its closure is $Y\cup\left\{(0,x)\,\middle|\,x\in[-1,1]\right\}$, which is not path-connected.